# SAPUI5 PlanningCalendar - binding two entities

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have the following problem:
I'm developing an APP using the flameworks PlanningCalendar, but I have two EntitySet:

```
Salas(3):
CAPACIDADE: 6
ID: 3
NOME: "SALA 3"
NavReservas: {__deferred: {…}}
__metadata: {type: "room_sfsf.rooms.SalasType", uri: "https://leandrp822648trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com:443/room_sfsf/rooms.xsodata/Salas(3)"}
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

and:

```
Reservas(1):
DATA_FIM: Tue Sep 18 2018 14:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília) {}
DATA_INICIO: Tue Sep 18 2018 12:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília) {}
ID: 1
ID_SALA: 3
NOME: "caio"
USUARIO: "caio.amorim"
__metadata:
type: "room_sfsf.rooms.ReservasType"
uri: "https://leandrp822648trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com:443/room_sfsf/rooms.xsodata/Reservas(1)
```

"
but I can not get the two to appear on the screen, but I can not get the two to appear on the related screen, Below is the view file:

```
<mvc:View
        controllerName="br.com.successfactors.itz.MeetingRoomSuccessfactors.controller.Main" 
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
        xmlns:unified="sap.ui.unified"
        xmlns="sap.m">
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
            <PlanningCalendar
                id="PC1"
                startDate="{path: '/startDate'}"

            rows="{path : '/Salas', parameters:{$expand: 'NavReservas'}}"

                appointmentSelect="handleAppointmentSelect"

                >
            <toolbarContent>
                <Title text="{i18n>title}" titleStyle="H4"/>
                <ToolbarSpacer/>
                <Button id="addButton" icon="sap-icon://add" press="handleAppointmentCreate" tooltip="Add"/>
            </toolbarContent>
            <rows>
                <PlanningCalendarRow
                        id="PCR"

                        title="{NOME}"
                        text="{i18n>QuantRoom} {CAPACIDADE}"


                        appointments="{path: '/Reservas', templateShareable: 'true'}"

                                >
                        <!--intervalHeaders="{path: 'Employees', templateShareable: 'true'}">-->
                    <appointments >
                        <unified:CalendarAppointment
                                startDate="{DATA_INICIO}"
                                endDate="{DATA_FIM}"
                                icon="{}"
                                title="{NOME}"
                                text="{USER}"
                                type="{}"
                                tentative="{}"

                                >
                        </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                    </appointments>
        <!--            <intervalHeaders>
                        <unified:CalendarAppointment
                                startDate="{start}"
                                endDate="{end}"
                                icon="{pic}"
                                title="{title}"
                                type="{type}">
                        </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                    </intervalHeaders>-->
                </PlanningCalendarRow>
            </rows>
        </PlanningCalendar>
    </VBox>
</mvc:View>
```

below the metadata file:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
    <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
        <Schema xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
            xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm"
            Namespace="room_sfsf.rooms">
            <EntityType Name="SalasType">
                <Key><PropertyRef Name="ID"/></Key><Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/><Property Name="NOME" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30"/><Property Name="CAPACIDADE" Type="Edm.Int32"/><NavigationProperty Name="NavReservas" Relationship="room_sfsf.rooms.Nav_ReservasType" FromRole="SalasPrincipal" ToRole="ReservasDependent"/></EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="ReservasType">
                <Key><PropertyRef Name="ID"/></Key><Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/><Property Name="NOME" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="30"/><Property Name="USUARIO" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20"/><Property Name="DATA_INICIO" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/><Property Name="DATA_FIM" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/><Property Name="ID_SALA" Type="Edm.Int32"/></EntityType>
            <Association Name="Nav_ReservasType"><End Type="room_sfsf.rooms.SalasType" Role="SalasPrincipal" Multiplicity="1"/><End Type="room_sfsf.rooms.ReservasType" Role="ReservasDependent" Multiplicity="*"/>
                <ReferentialConstraint>
                    <Principal Role="SalasPrincipal"><PropertyRef Name="ID"/></Principal>
                    <Dependent Role="ReservasDependent"><PropertyRef Name="ID_SALA"/></Dependent>
                </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <EntityContainer Name="rooms" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true"><EntitySet Name="Salas" EntityType="room_sfsf.rooms.SalasType"/><EntitySet Name="Reservas" EntityType="room_sfsf.rooms.ReservasType"/>
                <AssociationSet Name="Nav_Reservas" Association="room_sfsf.rooms.Nav_ReservasType"><End Role="SalasPrincipal" EntitySet="Salas"/><End Role="ReservasDependent" EntitySet="Reservas"/></AssociationSet>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

image with the result on screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzSZ2.png)
image the EntitySet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxWFh.png)

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this problem?
thank you so much.

**ADD NEW COMMENT**

I changed View after comment the Jorg, but not work, below:

```
<mvc:View
        controllerName="br.com.successfactors.itz.MeetingRoomSuccessfactors.controller.Main" 
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
        xmlns:unified="sap.ui.unified"
        xmlns="sap.m">
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
            <PlanningCalendar
                id="PC1"
                startDate="{path: '/startDate'}"

            rows="{path : '/Salas', parameters:{$expand: 'NavReservas'}}"

                appointmentSelect="handleAppointmentSelect"

                >
            <toolbarContent>
                <Title text="{i18n>title}" titleStyle="H4"/>
                <ToolbarSpacer/>
                <Button id="addButton" icon="sap-icon://add" press="handleAppointmentCreate" tooltip="Add"/>
            </toolbarContent>
            <rows>
                <PlanningCalendarRow
                        id="PCR"

                        title="{NOME}"
                        text="{i18n>QuantRoom} {CAPACIDADE}"


                        appointments="{path: 'NavReservas', templateShareable: 'true'}"

                                >
                        <!--intervalHeaders="{path: 'Employees', templateShareable: 'true'}">-->
                    <appointments >
                        <unified:CalendarAppointment
                                startDate="{DATA_INICIO}"
                                endDate="{DATA_FIM}"
                                icon="{}"
                                title="{NOME}"
                                text="{USER}"
                                type="{}"
                                tentative="{}"

                                >
                        </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                    </appointments>
        <!--            <intervalHeaders>
                        <unified:CalendarAppointment
                                startDate="{start}"
                                endDate="{end}"
                                icon="{pic}"
                                title="{title}"
                                type="{type}">
                        </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                    </intervalHeaders>-->
                </PlanningCalendarRow>
            </rows>
        </PlanningCalendar>
    </VBox>
</mvc:View>
```

Detail the error:

> Uncaught Error: "[object Object]" is of type object, expected
>   sap.ui.core.URI for property "icon" of Element
>   sap.ui.unified.CalendarAppointment#__appointment0-__xmlview0--PCR-__xmlview0--PC1-0-0
>       at f.g.validateProperty (sap-ui-core.js:423)
>       at f.M.validateProperty (/resources/sap/ui/core/library-preload.js?eval:181)
>       at f.g.setProperty (sap-ui-core.js:421)
>       at f.setIcon (sap-ui-core.js:509)
>       at f.g.updateProperty (sap-ui-core.js:464)
>       at constructor.v (sap-ui-core.js:462)
>       at constructor.a.fireEvent (sap-ui-core.js:397)
>       at constructor.B._fireChange (sap-ui-core.js:1463)
>       at constructor.O.checkUpdate (/resources/sap/ui/core/library-preload.js?eval:2480)
>       at constructor.O.initialize (/resources/sap/ui/core/library-preload.js?eval:2475)

Image Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE5jN.png)

the browser it work!

```
{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata": {"type":"room_sfsf.rooms.ReservasType","uri":"https://leandrp822648trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com:443/room_sfsf/rooms.xsodata/Reservas(1)"},"ID":1,"NOME":"caio","USUARIO":"caio.amorim","DATA_INICIO":"\/Date(1537311600000)\/","DATA_FIM":"\/Date(1537318800000)\/","ID_SALA":3}]}}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl9Sv.png)
Thanks.

Comment: My Portuguese is not great but... is there a relation between  `Salas` and `Reservas`? I see you have a navigation already, so you can use `{Nav_Reservas}` in the `appointments` part of the rows

Comment: Hi Jorg, 
I tried to do this, but it did not work!

Comment: Is a url like `Salas(3)/Nav_Reservas` returning the relevant results? You can try calling it in your browser first

Comment: the browser it work...
https://leandrp822648trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/room_sfsf/rooms.xsodata/Salas(3)/NavReservas/

Comment: After the edit, try not to use something like `icon="{}"`, if you don't have an icon, please remove that all together

Comment: Hello, Jorg, it worked !!!
Your guidance helped me a lot.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Here's what I did.
`<rows>
    <PlanningCalendarRow
      id="PCR"
      title="{NOME}"
      text="{i18n>QuantRoom} {CAPACIDADE}"
      appointments="{path: 'NavReservas', templateShareable: 'true'}"        >
     <appointments >
      <unified:CalendarAppointment
        startDate="{DATA_INICIO}"
        endDate="{DATA_FIM}"
        title="{NOME}"
        text="{USER}"
        >
      </unified:CalendarAppointment>
     </appointments>
    </PlanningCalendarRow>
   </rows> `